# Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI everyone im configure my robot arm in MOVEIT an works fine when i run demo.launch , but when i try to run it with gazebo, first i have this WARNING & ERROR :

```
[ INFO] [1578774737.136603131, 5.894000000]: waitForService: Service [/get_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...

[ WARN] [1578774739.157864263, 7.774000000]: Waiting for gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up

[ INFO] [1578774742.579925857, 10.914000000]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group? 
at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-moveit-ros-planning-0.9.17/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp:491

[ INFO] [1578774745.621015809, 13.362000000]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''

[ WARN] [1578774746.139798202, 13.776000000]: Waiting for gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up

[ERROR] [1578774753.258813815, 19.776000000]: Action client not connected: gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

And then when i created a new planning had the below warn and error:

```
[ INFO] [1578775095.446223626, 256.090000000]: ParallelPlan::solve(): Solution found by one or more threads in 0.027612 
seconds
[ INFO] [1578775095.446529469, 256.091000000]: RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure

[ INFO] [1578775095.446920003, 256.091000000]: RRTConnect: Starting planning with 1 states already in datastructure

[ INFO] [1578775095.458419074, 256.097000000]: RRTConnect: Created 6 states (2 start + 4 goal)

[ INFO] [1578775095.458526645, 256.097000000]: RRTConnect: Created 5 states (2 start + 3 goal)

[ INFO] [1578775095.459317195, 256.097000000]: ParallelPlan::solve(): Solution found by one or more threads in 0.012923 
seconds



  [ INFO] [1578775095.466620832, 256.104000000]: SimpleSetup: Path simplification took 0.007186 seconds and changed from 4 to 2 states

[ERROR] [1578775095.495185115, 256.126000000]: Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints.

[ WARN] [1578775095.496447441, 256.127000000]: Controller arm_controller failed with error code INVALID_JOINTS

[ WARN] [1578775095.499449045, 256.128000000]: Controller handle arm_controller reports status FAILED

[ INFO] [1578775095.499510155, 256.128000000]: Completed trajectory execution with status FAILED ...
```

This is my config file :

```
arm_controller:
  name: arm
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
  default: true
  joints:
    - shoulder
    - elbow
    - wrist
    - hand
  name: gripper
  type: "position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"

  default: true
  joints: 
    - right_knuckles
    - right_finger
    - left_knuckles
    - left_finger
```

You can find my URDF file in the follow [LINK](https://github.com/epsilon11101/URDF-MODEL/blob/master/urdf/dof_arm.urdf.xacro)

This error happens after add GRIPPER GROUP in MOVEIT
[image: image description]

I cant found solutions about this error , i hope you can help me!

Thanks for all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341525/joints-on-incoming-goal-don%27t-match-the-controller-joints./) by [Aaron MV](https://answers.ros.org/users/50723/aaron-mv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2020-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im solved it! , i  changed  my configuration files for gazebo and i replaced the controller.yaml generated by moveit thanks :)

---

Originally posted by [Aaron MV](https://answers.ros.org/users/50723/aaron-mv/) with karma: 76 on 2020-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nihalar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54529/nihalar/) on 2020-05-14**:
Could you share more details? I'm facing the same issue.

**Comment by [venkys](https://answers.ros.org/users/58650/venkys/) on 2020-08-27**:
I have the same problem but am unable to solve it. Can anyone please tell me how to solve the

```
[ERROR] [1598501928.491541561, 29.279000000]: Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints.
[ WARN] [1598501928.493957406, 29.281000000]: Controller panda_hand_controller failed with error INVALID_JOINTS:
```

I am extending my question here as I do not want to create a duplicate question

**Comment by [Aaron MV](https://answers.ros.org/users/50723/aaron-mv/) on 2020-08-31**:
Hi dude of course , you need to chance your ros control configurations,the joints needs to have the same name, change the yaml configurations

**Comment by [venkys](https://answers.ros.org/users/58650/venkys/) on 2020-09-02**:
I use a panda manipulator and the joint names in the /config/controls.yaml match the joints defined in the /description/panda.urdf file.

I have the the yaml file and move_group (thus urdf) exactly like the **config file** and **moveit image** you provided in the question. Both match already!!

It would be helpful if you can elaborate which yaml file change worked for you.

Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [qyp](https://answers.ros.org/users/73584/qyp/) on 2021-04-21**:
Hello, I also encountered the same problem as you. Can you give a more detailed explanation and change the yaml file specifically

[ERROR] [1619015960.636052504, 57.300000000]: Joints on incoming goal don't match the controller joints.
[ WARN] [1619015960.636390735, 57.300000000]: Controller robot/arm_joint_controller failed with error INVALID_JOINTS:
[ WARN] [1619015960.636534938, 57.300000000]: Controller handle robot/arm_joint_controller reports status FAILED